# C# Windows 8 XAML - Where add ApplicationData files?

Tags: xaml, asynchronous, store, storagefolder

I have a very simple question. I'am trying load async some files which should be located in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`, but where is that directory? How I should add some files to this folder?

Comment: why can't you print its value somewhere and see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7 or 8, it is located here (Assuming Windows is installed on `C:` drive):

`C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Local`

where `<your_user_name>` will be the currently Logged in username on the PC.

Comment: That directory I was looking is "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xx-xxx...\LocalState". I just want to know where I should add my dialogs file which from I parse text. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access this location directly, instead get a reference to it as a [StorageFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx):

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

then you can add or get a file:

```
StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName);

StorageFile file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(filename)
```